# Confusion related to modelling of temporal correlation

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

I was a bit confused about the modelling of temporal correlation in a certain paper. Lets say, I have vector $\bf{x}$ of dimension m, and a time series 
$\bf{x_1},\bf{x_2},...\bf{x_N}$. Now I want to model the temporal correlation of the data points.

So if I define

$\bf{x_n} = A\bf{x_{n-1}} + w_n$ where A is the parameter and $w= N(0,\tau)$, how does this model the temporal correlation of each dimension?

This might be a very basic question. But I really want to know how this models the correlation.

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you could define "temporal correlation" explicitly. Or, if your problem is that "temporal correlation" is used without a clear definition, it would help to describe the context where you're seeing it.